# AnimationDrawable is not working on 2.3.6 android version

Tags: android, android-animation

AnimationDrawable is not working on 2.3.6 android version.

Is there support library for older verions?

My code is:

```
iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashnew);
BitmapDrawable f0 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s1); 
BitmapDrawable f1 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s2); 
BitmapDrawable f2 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s3);
int dur = 850; 
AnimationDrawable ad = new AnimationDrawable();
ad.addFrame(f0, dur); 
ad.addFrame(f1, dur); 
ad.addFrame(f2, dur);
ad.start();
ad.setOneShot(true);
```

Comment: which drawable is not working can you please be more specific ?

Comment: my code is:   iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashnew);                                               
        BitmapDrawable f0 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s1);
        BitmapDrawable f1 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s2);
        BitmapDrawable f2 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s3);
    
        int dur = 850;
        Ad = new AnimationDrawable();
        Ad.addFrame(f0, dur);
        Ad.addFrame(f1, dur);
        Ad.addFrame(f2, dur);
        Ad.start();
       Ad.setOneShot(true);

Comment: you should put this code in question

Comment: I added my code in question..

Comment: AnimationDrawable exists since API level 1, so I don't think there is need for a support library. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Its showing only first frame.Its not showing remaining frames.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got the answer:

You should start the animation in a runnable.

```
    iv.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
             ad.start();
             ad.setOneShot(true); // use this if you want to run the animation only once
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashnew);
BitmapDrawable f0 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s1); 
BitmapDrawable f1 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s2); 
BitmapDrawable f2 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s3);
int dur = 850; 
AnimationDrawable ad = new AnimationDrawable();
ad.addFrame(f0, dur); 
ad.addFrame(f1, dur); 
ad.addFrame(f2, dur);
iv.setBackgroundDrawable(ad);
iv.post(new Runnable(){
    public void rub(){
         ad.start();
}
}
```